# how can I sperate postgresql logfile?

Tags: postgresql, logfile

In postgresql.conf, log_filename set like 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'.
So, logfile created only one.
Can I separate logfile by session or host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-logging.html), `log_filename` uses strftime like parameters. It seems you can't separate file name by anything else than date format. However, you can use `log_line_prefix` to add session pid or client host into log lines.

Comment: Thanks about your respone